# What is convention based framework?

Tags: frameworks

I'm reading about [ColdBox](http://www.coldbox.org/about), and I came across this word.

So what is meant by convention based framework?

Comment: not sure but I heard something simular recently that might help you look... they were talking about convention-over-configuration

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like BitOff mentions, it means what others [convention over configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration).  This seems to be confirmed by the ColdBox home page.

Basically, this means that instead of having configuration files describing details about a project - where to find files, which classes to instantiate, which URLs map to which classes, and so forth - the framework provides good defaults that allow you to just put the files and classes and methods in the right place and be done with it.

Answer (score 2):

It means that details that usually do not carry any semantic (that is, any meaning) are used by the framework to generate a default configuration. It is also known as "convention over configuration".

For example, in Ruby on Rails, if you use a class named Customer, the generated database table will automatically be named "customers".